# If two observers look at the same quantum object, will they see the same thing?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, interferometry, radiometry

Let's say two observers, one at the North pole and one at the South pole, both observe the Moon. Will they see the same Moon, or a subtly different Moon?

Intuitively it feels like they should see a different Moon - this is because each individual Moon photon can only be detected by one of the two observers. However if this is the case, then why would astronomical radio interferometry work? After all, there's no reason to suppose the photons each observer detects would be similar/coherent enough to interfere with the photons detected by the other observer.

Comment: What do you mean by "see the same Moon"?  As you wrote, two distinct observers do not detect the same photons reflected off of the Moon.  But the photons they detect were reflected off the *same* Moon.  Would you mind clarifying your question in this regard?

Comment: See the same Moon = everything they could conceivably measure about the Moon's properties (temperature, albedo, etc etc etc) are the same.

Comment: It is impossible to measure anything with perfect accuracy, even ignoring quantum effects. Define exactly what you mean by "the measured properties are *the same*."

Comment: could you pick a different example than the Moon/radio astronomy? You would need to go down to cryogenic temperatures before you can reliably detect single microwave photon.

Comment: @alephzero I don't understand. The measured properties are equal to within experimental error - that seems like the common-sense definition.

Comment: @IamAStudent I'd prefer to keep radio astronomy because that's integral to the problem in the second paragraph.

Comment: well then single optical photon and two CCD pixels would be a more fitting example....

Comment: On a more serious note, are you asking about effects of measurement on quantum states or about how astronomical interferometer works? If it's the former, I feel the question is too broad (e.g. specify what kind of measurement/detection is performed) and if it is the latter, there is no quantum mechanical phenomena happening.

Comment: @IamAStudent this is more a question about interferometry than measurement. What makes you say there's no QM phenomena happening?

Comment: there is no QM happening in that the signal you observe is a classical wave. You don't need to describe the signal you get as photons.

Comment: @IamAStudent but QM should also be able to describe the signal?

Comment: well, yes but to little benefit I think. QM does add something else that classical physics does not (photon shot noise), but again for radio waves, thermal fluctuation will swamp shot noise. It seems to me that you are concerned more with coherence / phase noise in the signal you observe. Could you clarify/update your question regarding that? I will prevent myself from adding extra comments after this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the astronomers can measure quantum-scale properties of the moon, they will definitely obtain different results at that scale.  That's not really because they measure "different photons," though, but because outcomes of measurements of a noisy quantum system with a vast number of component subsystems will have prohibitively small probabilities of repeating.

However, radio interferometry is classical, not quantum interferometry, so it works just fine because any quantum effects are statistically washed out.  After all, Michelson and Morley did their famous interference experiment with white light from a non-coherent source before quantum mechanics was even studied.

Answer (score 3):

I think @Allure is asking 1) if a single quantum object (whose state is indeterminate) can be measured separately and independently by two different observers, and 2) if so, then can they get different results.

The answer is basically "yes" to 1) and "no" 2). An entangled pair of particles is, for all practical purposes, a single quantum object.  Observer A can measure one of the pair, while Observer B measures the other of the pair.  By doing their measurements on the quantum object, the observers entangle themselves with the quantum object. The only way the two observers can know if they have gotten different results is by comparing results, which entangles the observers.  As a result, both observers are entangled with the quantum object so they will agree on its state.